# rails 3 postgres array support

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

i have a query in postgres that returns back a postgres array in one of the columns:

```
SELECT e.context->'device' AS device, count(e.data->'model_name') AS members, ARRAY_AGG(e.data->'model_name') AS models
  FROM entity AS e
  WHERE e.data->'type'='chassis' GROUP BY e.context->'device', e.data->'model_name';
```

is there a gem or `serialize` statement i could use to map the rails 3 model so that i could use `models` directly as a ruby array?

i know i could loop through it in the controller, but that seems not very DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to close this out: in the end i upgraded to rails4. it has great support for both arrays and hashes.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone finds this and like me is looking to add support to a Rails 3.2 app I found the [1.0 version of postgres_ext gem](https://github.com/DockYard/postgres_ext/tree/v1.0.0).

The 1.0 version has a dependency on ActiveRecord 3.2.

Higher major versions are for use with Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have been able to find is [activerecord-postgres-array](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-postgres-array).  It isn't clear how well maintained it is, but in general the actual code is not too complex or unstable and so I would expect it would be reasonable to work with.

I say this as someone who used to process these manually in Perl before DD::Pg got direct support for Pg arrays.  The code is simple and relatively unchanging, and so the fact that there are a number of releases in the past suggests that this is where to start.